# The difference between <str:slug> and <slug:slug> in urls.py of Django application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

1. Why in some cases in urls.py is used str:slug, and in other cases
   slug:slug? What is the difference? And which option is better to
   use?
2. And can I use a category slug and then an article slug in one
   route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why in some cases in urls.py is used `str:slug`, and in other cases `slug:slug`? What is the difference?

The [*path converter* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) is different. Indeed, the `<str:slug>` will accept a different set of strings (in this case a strict superset) than the strings the `<slug:slug>` will accept.

The documentation explains what will be matched:

> - `str` - Matches any non-empty string, excluding the path separator, '/'. This is the default if a converter isn’t included in the
>   expression.
> - `slug` - Matches any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters. For example,
>   building-your-1st-django-site.

The `str` will thus match any non-empty string, it will thus accept `'foo'`, `'straße'`, `'foo bar'`, whereas the `slug` path convert will only exist as a non-empty sequence of ASCII letters and numbers and hyphens and underscores.

We can also see this in the [implementation of the `StringConverter` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/urls/converters.py#L15-L22) and the [implementation of the `SlugConverter` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/urls/converters.py#L35-L36):

> ```
> class StringConverter:
>     regex = '[^/]+'
>
>     def to_python(self, value):
>         return value
>
>     def to_url(self, value):
>         return value
>
> # ⋮
>
> class SlugConverter(StringConverter):
>     regex = '[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+'
> ```

The `StringConverter` will thus use the `[^/]+` regex, whereas the slug converter will match with the `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+` regex.

Usually if you work with slugs, it is better to work with the slug path converter, since this will *not* match with non-slugs, and usually one matches with slugs, not with strings.

A slug has been introduced to work with a pretty looking URL. A URL where the URL parameter contains a space will be replaced by *ugly* percentage encoding, so `foo%20bar`, whereas a slug will normally use a hyphen, so `foo-bar`.

> And can I use a category slug and then an article slug in one route?

Sure you can define a path with:

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:article_slug>/', some_view)
```

The `some_view` will in that case accept three parameters, so:

```
def some_view(request, category_slug, article_slug):
    # …
    pass
```